# SSRS 2008 R2 excel export not work on report server

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

In an SSRS 2008 R2 report, I have the following expression on the 'Hidden' property on the Tablixes where I
do not want the headings exported to EXCEL or PDF.

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "PDF", True, False)
```

The code listed above works fine when I am using my visual studio bids IDE.
However when I deploy the code listed above to the test report server, the following occurs:

1. The heading columns for PDF do not show up, however
2. The headings columns show up when I export the SSRS report to EXCEL on the report server.

I do not understand why the code would work on the visual studio ide and it does not work on the report server.

I also want to mention that when I change the code to the following:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "PDF", False, True),
```

that:

1. the Excel report headings show up on visual studio and
2. the Excel report headings do not show up on the report server.

Thus can you tell me what could be causing this problem and what I can do to solve the problem?
What code should I use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are grouping your report and have nested groups then the following should suffice:
GROUP A
GROUP B
GROUP C

```
<GROUP A>.Row Visibility=Parameters!RenderFormat.Value="EXCEL"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am not using nested groups. Thus do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Can you make a test =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL",true,IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF",true,false))